# Unexpected value of Long variable after converting to char array

Tags: java, char, long-integer

`1. long number = 564;
 2.     String str = number+"";
 3.     char[] num = str.toCharArray();
 4.          number = number - num[0]; 
                  /* The value of number is 511 */`

I am trying to subtract the first digit of the number from the number using this piece of code.

During debugging, i found out that the value of num[0] was 53. Can anyone explain what am i missing here.

Comment: `53` is the ASCII code for the character `5`

Comment: Thanks, @M.M, but i want the number to be 559. Is it possible to convert 53 to 5 somehow?

Comment: You could subtract 48 ?

Comment: A `char` is a number in the range 0 to 65535, but the _characters_ (usually visible characters but sometimes "control characters" or other characters that have special meaning) associated with those numbers are defined by Unicode.  [Here is a link to the first 4096 characters.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF).  Note that the digit 5 is at the position 0x0035 (which is 53 in decimal).

Comment: Subtracting 48 is the normal way to accomplish this.  Or since `'0'` has the value 48, you can say `ch - '0'` where `ch` is a `char`.

Comment: @ajb a better way is `Character.getNumericValue(ch)`. Its intent is more obvious, and works for non-ASCII numbers too.

Comment: @AndyTurner cool, I didn't realize this function existed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to change your fourth line to this:

```
number = number - Long.parseLong(Character.toString(num[0]));
```

Basically, what is happening here is that I first convert the `char` (`num[0]`) to a string, then parsed the string to a `long`.

ALternatively, you don't even need to convert the string to a char array! Use `charAt()` to get the char:

```
number = number - Long.parseLong(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the binary operator  "-"  the smaller datatype, in this case char, is promoted to long which returns the ASCII value of num[0] ('5') which is 53. To get the actual face value of num[0] convert it to String and parse it to Long as Sweeper has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

It just feels wrong to convert a number to a string, extract the first char, convert back to number and subtract. Why don't you extract the first digit while working with numbers directly. Something like this would do:

```
    long number = 564;

    int digits = 0;
    assert (number > 0);
    for (long num = number; num > 1; num = num / 10 ) {
        digits += 1;
    }
    int firstDigit = (int) (number / Math.pow(10, digits -1));

    number = number - firstDigit;
    System.out.println(number);
```

If you want to get all digits:

```
    long number = 564;

    int digits = 0;
    assert (number > 0);
    for (long num = number; num > 1; num = num / 10 ) {
        digits += 1;
    }

    for (int digit = digits - 1; digit >= 0; digit--) {
        int currentDigit = (int) (number / Math.pow(10, digit)) % 10;
        System.out.println(currentDigit);
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the first digit. In order to find other digits similar procedure would be better or "the string" approach?

Comment: I 'd propose similar approach (numbers - not strings). The modification needed is straightforward. I ll update my answer.